# change theme of button using jQuery mobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

i have downloaded the theme file from the jQuerymobile site but the theme is not getting applied to my button,where am i wrong?
here in html file i have imported it like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/my-custom-theme.css" />    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet"
 href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.2.min.css" /> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

and the code for button is

```
 <a href="iheadache.html" data-theme="a" style="height:30px;" class="ui-btn">
 Add a log</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the class ui-btn and add the data-role="button" and it should work.

```
<a data-role="button" href="iheadache.html" data-theme="a" style="height:30px;">
 Add a log</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that you use jQuery Mobile 1.4.2.

The `data-theme="a"` works on this version but you can also use the class `class="ui-btn-a"`

You can check this on the doc : http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/button-markup/